# SDL2. Why I'm getting a Segmentation Fault in the free() function? Also, am I doing the rendering stuff right?

Tags: sdl2, c

So, I'm new at C programming and SDL2 and I'm trying to get something working here to write some games. First, I would like to know if I'm doing the rendering stuff the right way.

I'm kind of confused about the software and hardware rendering. Here I'm using a `SDL_Texture` and `SDL_LockTexture` to write raw pixels into it. I would like to know if I should use `SDL_Surface` instead, and, how can I get the best performance out of the hardware.

I allocate the memory for the pixels in the `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED`, which is called the first time a window appears, and everytime the window is resized, so then I can reallocate a new memory for the new window size.

For that to work, I need to `SDL_DestroyTexture` and `free(pixels)` to allocate newer ones in a new resized `SDL_Texture`, at least I think I need. The problem is... I'm getting a Segmentation Fault right in the `free()` call, according to GDB (GNU Debugger), and I don't know why, it's probably some stupid beginner error.

It is important to mention that, in the first `while(running)` iteration, the function `free()` is not called, so, the SegFault only happens the first time I resize the window. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h> // fprintf, printf

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

typedef struct
{
  SDL_Texture* texture;
  void* pixels;
  int width;
  int height;
  int pitch;
  int bytes_per_pixel;

} Render_Buffer;

void rendering_testing(Render_Buffer* render_buffer)
{
  if(SDL_LockTexture(render_buffer->texture,
                     NULL,
                     &render_buffer->pixels,
                     &render_buffer->pitch) != 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to lock SDL texture: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
  }
  else
  {
    uint8* row_first_byte = (uint8*)render_buffer->pixels;

    for(uint16 y = 0; y < render_buffer->height; ++y)
    {
      uint32* pixel = (uint32*)row_first_byte;

      for(uint16 x = 0; x < render_buffer->width; ++x)
      {
        *pixel++ = 0x00ff00ff;
      }

      row_first_byte += render_buffer->pitch;
    }

    SDL_UnlockTexture(render_buffer->texture);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_AUDIO) != 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return -1;
  }

  int window_width = 640;
  int window_height = 480;

  SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Breakout",
                                        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                        window_width,
                                        window_height,
                                        SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE
#ifndef DEBUG
                                        |SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP
#endif
                                        );
  if(window == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create SDL window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    SDL_Quit();
    return -1;
  }

  SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1,
                                              SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED|
                                              SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
  if(renderer == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create SDL renderer: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return -1;
  }

  Render_Buffer render_buffer = {0};
  render_buffer.bytes_per_pixel = 4;

  bool8 running = true;
  while(running)
  {
    SDL_Event event;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
      switch(event.type)
      {
        case SDL_QUIT:
        {
          running = false;
        } break;

        case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:
        {
          switch(event.window.event)
          {
            case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED:
            {
              if(render_buffer.texture)
              {
                SDL_DestroyTexture(render_buffer.texture);
              }

              SDL_GetWindowSize(window, &window_width, &window_height);
#ifdef DEBUG
              printf("window width: %d\nwindow height: %d\n", window_width, window_height);
#endif
              render_buffer.width = window_width;
              render_buffer.height = window_height;

              render_buffer.texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer,
                                                        SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888,
                                                        SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING,
                                                        render_buffer.width,
                                                        render_buffer.height);

              if(render_buffer.texture == NULL)
              {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create SDL texture: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
                SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
                SDL_Quit();
                running = false;
                return -1;
              }

              if(render_buffer.pixels)
              {
                free(render_buffer.pixels); // SEGFAULT HAPPENS HERE!!!
              }

              render_buffer.pixels = malloc(render_buffer.width *
                                            render_buffer.height *
                                            render_buffer.bytes_per_pixel);

              render_buffer.pitch = render_buffer.width * render_buffer.bytes_per_pixel;

            } break;

            default:
            {
              // TODO
            }
          }
        } break;

        default:
        {
          // TODO
        }
      }
    }

    rendering_testing(&render_buffer);

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, render_buffer.texture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
  }

  SDL_DestroyTexture(render_buffer.texture);
  SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_Quit();

  return 0;
}
```

Should I use `malloc()` and `free()` or something else instead?

What can I do to solve this SegFault error? What can I do the get the best performance out of the renderer while writing pixels manually into the memory, and what is the right way to do that? What can I do better that I'm not doing here?

For now, thanks so much for the attention!

Comment: Your segfault is happening because you're calling free on already freed memory. SDL_DestroyTexture frees the memory managed by the SDL_Texture that you 'Destroy'.

Comment: Also you shouldn't be destroying your renderer, window and quitting SDL until you're out of that loop, you're currently doing each twice, under certain scenarios, you should be fine to just leave the calls to those functions at the end of your main() for now, where you have another set of them. In general you shouldn't need more than one call to SDL_Init(). Also one call to SDL_Quit(), and only after you're completely done destroying/freeing up everything else related to SDL.

Comment: @JoshuaHedges you are dam right! Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh, but, if I manage to write only one SDL_Quit() at the end of the main() function, I will need to write a bunch of if's and else's. Do you think it's a better programming practice to not write a bunch of `return` in the middle of the code and instead use a `return_value` int variable to use at the end of the program? I dont think it's such a big deal to do that. Actually, the SDL wiki always call `return` when checking for a feature initialization in the middle of the code.

Comment: Hey @JoshuaHedges, the SDL_DestroyTexture is not freeing my pixels memory. When I resize the window and look to the memory usage in the task manager, it only gets bigger. If pixels were freed, the memory usage should increase and decrease when resizing the window.

Comment: It's better practice to put your setup and shutdown in separate functions like AppSetup and AppShutdown or something, and that's also where you'd include things like script language and rendering or audio engine startup and shutdown, then use those functions in main. It's also better practice to keep one return value that is, if it's state and purpose is clear, like "setup_error" could be a simple int/boolean (boolean is int but behaves different due to macros when you pull in stdbool.h). It's not a problem where your returns are located, but functions would help organize it all.

Comment: The task window won't show stable memory usage because a lot of the resources are managed by the operating system, though it shouldn't deviate by too much. should be reusing the texture, and even using it's internal pixel surface, rather than maintaining your own pixel buffer. SDL_Texture has a pixel buffer, You should use SDL_CreateTexture. If you could update your code to show your most recent work then I can help better and write an answer that should help you resolve your issue, and be started in a good direction.

Answer (score 1):

After the `SDL_UnlockTexture` the pointer to the pixels gets invalidated. From SDL
documentation

> As an optimization, the pixels made available for editing don't
> necessarily contain the old texture data. This is a write-only
> operation, and if you need to keep a copy of the texture data you
> should do that at the application level.

Also is explained in LazyFoo's documentation.

> After the texture is unlocked the pixel pointer is invalid so we set it to NULL.